# ::after pseudo element overflowing element, using overflow:hidden; has extra space

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to make a button with a hover effect and `::after` pseudo class is involved.

The `::after` pseudo-class covers 100% of the button's height and width, even more just to be sure; then when `:hover`, the `::after` element's width will shrink to 0.

My problem is that I can't precisely size the `::after` element, so I simply added `overflow: hidden;` to the button so that it will cut out the overflowing parts of the `::after` pseudo-element. But it cropped a little too much, leaving one pixel between the border  and the `::after` pseudo-element covering the button.

```css
.btn {
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #EF9C43;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: color 0.3s, transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 4rem rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.5);
  z-index: 5;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: #EF9C43;
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  transform: translateY(-0.3rem);
  box-shadow: 1rem 1.5rem 2rem rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.6);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  box-shadow: 1rem 1.25rem 2.5rem rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.5);
}

.btn:hover::after {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn--orange">Hire our services</button>
```

Here is the codepen of my case: https://codepen.io/CoolBoiDave/pen/bGLdwxE

Any help would be appreciated! (PS: sorry for bad english)

Comment: *Offtopic:* Hover your button slowly from the bottom... welcome to bad UI design :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ah I did not notice that! Thank you for the info, I will fix it :)

Comment: I brought the code from your linked Codepen demo into the question, though as [SO] doesn't have a compiler for SCSS I did have to compile that SCSS to plain CSS; this means your question *may* attract answers that need to be converted back to SCSS (sorry).

Comment: @DavidThomas All good. Thanks for helping me with the post!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why would you use an ::after pseudo element when all you need is to
transition a `background-image`.
Also, you could use an **inset box-shadow** instead of  `border`.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  font: 400 2.3rem sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: color .3s, background-position .3s, box-shadow .3s;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 4rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 0 0 3px #EF9C43;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,145,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
  background-size: 200%;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-position: 100%;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 2rem rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 0 0 3px #EF9C43;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn--orange">Hire our services</button>
```

Comment: sorry, but the ::after pseudo class method was the first thing I thought about when making this button. Thank you for the alternative solution!